# Click event error: cannot implicitly convert type string to system date and time

Tags: c#, asp.net

This gives me error at the last if condition under button 1 click event shows error that cannot implicitly convert type string to system date and time what changes should be done?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    if (DateTime.Now.Hour < 12)
    {
        lblGreeting.Text = "Good Morning";

    }
    else if (DateTime.Now.Hour < 17)
    {
        lblGreeting.Text = "Good Afternoon";

    }
    else
    {
        lblGreeting.Text = "Good Evening";

    }


}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (DateTime.Now.Date = TextBox2.Text)
   {
       Label2.Text = "Happy Birthday";
   }
   else
   {
       Label2.Text = "Have a nice day";

   }
}
```

Comment: `if (DateTime.Now.Date = TextBox2.Text)
`  is your attempt to compare dates. Comparing a date with text is like comparing apples with oranges. (btw, it should be == for a comparison) So you need to parse the text as a date, see DateTime.TryParse

Comment: This is not a comparison but an assign

Comment: @ruchit patel use equals for object comparison. == compares references, = does not compare anything, it assigns

Comment: For your information, really vague titles are downvoted quickly here. "Please help me with this program" could apply to all 14.4M questions on the site. Would you improve it? What single-sentence question would you ask to give us a clue about what technology you are using and the problem you are encountering?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to compare `DateTime.Now.Date` with `TextBox2.Text`

First you shouldn't use `=` for comparison of two variables, you should use `==` to check if a variable is equal to another.

The point is that you cant't compare a `string` with `DateTime`. That's why the exception was thrown.

Use `DateTime.TryParse` method to parse a string to DateTime, then compare it with another DateTime (use `CompareTo(DateTime value)` method).

See the document [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.95).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the **[`DateTime.Parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx)** method to convert the text to Date first,and use == for **`comparison`** instead of = which is **`assign`**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DateTime txtMyDate = DateTime.Parse(TextBox2.Text);
   if (DateTime.Now.Date == txtMyDate)
   {
       Label2.Text = "Happy Birthday";
   }
   else
   {
       Label2.Text == "Have a nice day";

   }
}
```